# Запрос для Google Sheets, вывод списка по условию

Tags: sql, google-spreadsheet

пытаюсь написать запрос для гугл таблиц, который должен выводить 10 товаров которые в сумме дают указанное число(условные 30), и тут назревает вопрос, как возможно это реализовать?
Нашёл данное решение, но тут появился вопрос, как указать количество необходимых строк для вывода, и преобразовать для гугл запроса?

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *,
        @sum := @sum + price SUM
    FROM product,
        (SELECT @sum := 0) s) total
WHERE
    SUM <= 100
```

Comment: Возможно вы в поисках оконных функций?

Comment: Возможно прозвучит глупо, но в гугл таблицах они имеются?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls

Comment: Благодарю за информацию